# PreciseQMA = PreciseBQP gives PP = PSPACE

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory, computational-models

$\text{PreciseBQP}$ is defined as $\text{BQP}$ with inverse exponentially close completeness and soundness bounds (for a better definition, see Section 3.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11139), in the paper by Gharibian et al). Similarly, $\text{PreciseQMA}$ is $\text{QMA}$ with inverse exponentially close completeness and soundness gaps (for more details, see Remark 5 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.01975), in the paper by Fefferman and Lin). It is known that
\begin{equation}
\text{PreciseBQP} = \text{PP}, \\
\text{PreciseQMA} = \text{PSPACE}.
\end{equation}

For more details, see Figure 1 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.11582) (paper by Deshpande et al). However, it seems obvious to me that
\begin{equation}
\text{PreciseQMA} \subseteq \text{PreciseBQP}.
\end{equation}
This is because one can simply replace the quantum witness given by the prover by the maximally mixed state, similar to the trick in Theorem 3.6 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0506068), in the Marriott. We take an inverse exponential hit in the completeness and soundness bounds, but since the completeness and soundness bounds are inverse exponentially close in $\text{PreciseBQP}$, to begin with, we do not care.

However, if this is true, then it implies $\text{PP} = \text{PSPACE}$.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess a similar argument used

- in $\big[$ Marriot, Watrous $\big] $ [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0506068)
  to prove QMA$_{log}$ $\subseteq$ BQP

and

- in $\big[$ Fefferman, Lin $\big]$ [[2]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.01975)
  to prove QMA$_{exp}$ $\subseteq$ PSPACE

does not carry over since for L $\in $ QMA$_{exp}$ = PreciseQMA you get

- $ x \in $ L $ \implies \text{tr}[Q_x] \geq c $
- $ x \notin $ L $ \implies \text{tr}[Q_x] \leq 2^m s $

for $ c - s = \frac{1}{exp} $ and so using the totally mixed state $2^{-m} \mathbb{I}_m $ you accept with probability $ \text{tr}[2^{-m} Q_x] $ but does not yield any meaningful bound.

Both papers essentially apply an amplification procedure before the argument.